# env file - semicolon is automatically added at the end

Tags: prettier, dotenv

[image]

As you can see the screen, in my `.env`file, semicolon is automatically added at the end.

And front and behind the `=` there comes space between `=` also automatically.

Problem is when I get data from env file, like `process.env.ACCOUNT_SID`, if I console.log this variable, then it shows data with `;`. So it doesn't work as a key.

`VAb57c6dd85cee7e3c8975857c2bd54a1c;`

So I need to remove semicolon by my self like `process.env.ACCOUNT_SID.replace(";", "")`.

Then it works.

`VAb57c6dd85cee7e3c8975857c2bd54a1c`

I don't know which setting makes this happen. I use prettier.

how can I change this format not to put semicolon at the end?

Comment: where is screen of you `.env` file. please add proper tag for question.

Comment: I add picture now

Comment: Exchanged the *javascript* tag for the *prettier* tag, since you don't have an issue with javascript. If you use prettier, what is your configuration then? You could add your `.prettierrc` here or share your IDE's configuration.

Comment: i think in your project there is some formatter which add this in your file, you have to exclude `*.env` file from there configurations.

Comment: add file `.prettierignore` in your project root if you use `prettier` as formatter and add `*.env` for ignoring file which extension end with `.env`.